# Connecting ASP.NET MVC with Database, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stripe.net

I'm trying to create a record in my database with Stripe server response values, i.e, I'll be getting a response in javascript and I've to update my model. For this, I'm creating a model variable in database :

```
var values = {
    "CardType": response.card.brand,
    "Name": response.card.name,
    "LastFour": response.card.last4,
    "Email" : @Membership.GetUser().Email,
    "Token": response.id
}
```

And then I'm trying to update my table using a method I have created in the controller:

**This is how I make the call**

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Create")",values,function(data)
{
    alert("I have reached here");
});
```

**And this is my Create Method in the controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CardInfo newCard)
{
    ViewBag.StripeKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripePublishableKey"];
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.CardInfoes.Add(newCard);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("About");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(newCard);
    }
}
```

After all these when I try to launch the page, I get a huge error message with a heading :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

PS. I have tried an ajax call and got the same issue

Comment: **I meant to say: I'm creating a variable with model attributes in JavaScript**

Comment: What is your connection string? did you make sure that SQL is accessible from your web server and you can connect to it using Sql management studio? sometimes you need to enable remote  connections if SQL was on another server

Answer (score 0):

You could set a break point at line

```
db.CardInfoes.Add(newCard);
```

And verify the db context is using correct connection string.

Comment: This error comes up when I try to launch the Create View in my webpage

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer